# I would like make a function begin at the top of the hour, every hour (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function `hello_world ()` that I would like to call every hour (1:00, 2:00, 3:00, etc).

I'm a beginner here and not totally comfortable with writing loops.

I have the following code, but it stops after 23 hours. I am not sure how to loop the loop such that everything repeats at the end of the day!

```
def sched ():
    i = 0

    for  (i <= 23):
        x = datetime.today()
        current_hour = datetime.now().hour
        y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=i, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
        delta_t=y-x
        secs=delta_t.seconds+1
        t=Timer(secs, hello_world)
        t.start()
        i = i + 1
```

I also realize this may not be the most efficient way of writing this code, so I am open to suggestions on how to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about modulo operator (%)? i % 24 will return the remainder after dividing by 24, so i will be 0, 1, .. 23, 0 .. etc

```
def sched ():
    i = 0

    while True:
        x = datetime.today()
        current_hour = datetime.now().hour
        y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=i, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
        delta_t=y-x
        secs=delta_t.seconds+1
        t=Timer(secs, hello_world)
        t.start()
        i = i + 1
        i = i % 24
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you limited your loop to `i <= 23`.  You can change it to this:

```
i = 0
while True:
    x = datetime.today()
    current_hour = datetime.now().hour
    y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=i, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
    delta_t=y-x
    secs=delta_t.seconds+1
    t=Timer(secs, hello_world)
    t.start()
    i = (i + 1) % 24
```

Using `(i + 1) % 24` guarentees that `i` will never be greater than `23`.  More about the modulus operator [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).